# Weird header can't be included in both main.cpp and window.cpp (a class)

Tags: mingw, static-linking, redefinition, .lib, hinstance

I have to create a static-linking standalone .exe file from my .cpp and .h files.

The only obstacle I need to overcome is being able to call the same function `m_pListAll()`from two .cpp files, `main.cpp` and `window.cpp` (defining a class called `Window`).

The only problem is (for unknown reasons) I cannot `#include` the header file that defines m_peDO() twice across `main.cpp` and `window.cpp`, I can only do it once because the header file sets up something called "dynamic linking" with some bizarre thing called `HINSTANCE`(wrong: actual reason is in answer section):

```
            //linking.h

            //  This is an extra header file for dynamic linking of the LabJackUD driver.
            //  support@labjack.com

            #ifdef  __cplusplus
            extern "C"
            {
            #endif 

            //For dynamic linking, we first define structures that have the same format
            //as the desired function prototype.
            typedef LJ_ERROR (CALLBACK *tListAll) (long, long, long *, long *, long *, double *);


            //Define a variable to hold a handle to the loaded DLL.
            HINSTANCE hDLLInstance;

            //Define variables for the UD functions.
            tListAll m_pListAll;

            #ifdef  __cplusplus
            } // extern C
            #endif
```

There are more functions, but lets just pretend I want to use tListAll m_pListAll in main.cpp and window.cpp. My Qt project contains the following files:

```
main.cpp //main code
window.h //header defining a class used in main
window.cpp //cpp thing defining that class's methods
peripheral.h //header file to control my peripheral device
peripheral.lib //library file to control my peripheral device (VC6 only not minGW?!)
linking.h //thing that solves(?) the minGW/VC6 library incompatibility (read on)

Scenario 1) #include <linking.h> in **only** main.cpp
Outcome: m_pListAll() only in scope of main.cpp, out of scope for window.cpp
Scenario 2) #include <linking.h> in **both** main.cpp AND window.cpp
Outcome: Redefinition errors for redefining hDLLInstance and m_pListAll().
```

Why am I using this wierd HINSTANCE thing? Something to do with my .lib file being incompatible with minGW. If I add the library to statically be part of compilation, i get:
    :-1: error: No rule to make target 'C:/Users/Joey/Documents/ValvePermissions/libLabJackU.a', needed by 'release\ValvePermissions.exe'.  Stop.

What should I do? I just want that function to be in the scope of window.cpp, but I don't want to use that header twice because of the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you've *defined* `hDLLInstance` and `m_pListAll` in the header, rather than simply *declare* them; thus *every* translation unit which includes this header will create a *public implementation* of each of these variables, all of which collide at link time.

You need to add the `extern` keyword to each of these definitions in the header, thus converting them to *declarations*, **and** copy your original definitions, (i.e. **without** the `extern` keyword), into **just one** of your translation units, (`main.cpp` perhaps), so that there is exactly one implementation *defined* at link time. Thus, in your header, you have:

```
//Declare a variable to hold a handle to the loaded DLL.
extern HINSTANCE hDLLInstance;

//Declare variables for the UD functions.
extern tListAll m_pListAll;
```

and in `main.cpp`, (for example):

```
//Define a variable to hold a handle to the loaded DLL.
HINSTANCE hDLLInstance;

//Define variables for the UD functions.
tListAll m_pListAll;
```